# UWP in-process AppService launching UI

Tags: c#, uwp, .net-core

I would like to create an UWP App (e.g. AppSwitch) in WinIot Core, which communicates with two different UWP apps.
In some situations the AppSwitch application only has to communicate with the other apps and depending on the communication, the AppSwitch has to display some Status information and needs to get the foreground app.

For that I was thinking to create a foreground app having an in-process AppService. But how is it possible to display the status information, if the apps was never Launched (OnActivated) but only started as AppService (OnBackgroundActivated). Can I get from OnBackgroundActivated to the UI if never launched?

Thanks
Schaf

Comment: You can display a toast notification from the background task. Bringing the actual app UI to the foreground from a background task is not allowed for Store apps. Let me know if your scenario is not a Store app.